# virtual env path is not loaded when using gunicorn

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have a script that loads a pip installed in a `virtualenv`

```
from google.cloud import pubsub
```

when I run the script like so

```
(my_virtual_environment): python script.py
```

it works. BUT when I run it via `gunicorn`

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py script.py
```

I get

```
from google.cloud import pubsub
ImportError: No module named cloud
```

when I print the `sys.path` in both cases , I get that the `sys.path` in one case includes the virtualenv path

```
[......., /Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/my_virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',......]
```

and in the other case (running via `gunicorn`), I don't see it. 
when Running `pip freeze` , `gunicorn` is present.

Answer (score 1):

so , it turns out that gunicorn defaults to where it was previously loaded.

My solution was to cd in the directory and then run the `gunicorn` command

```
cd my_directory
<loads the virtualenv> using auto env # workon my_virtualenv
gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py script.py
```